# Atom is creating a filename.o in home directory after compiling and running a c++ file using gpp compiler package

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, atom-editor

I am using atom editor for my C++ related works. But while compiling and running the C++ file using gpp compiler package, a filename.o file is created in the home directory. This is happening each time I am compiling and running my code. Is there any solution to this problem?

[Image for the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgYvM.png)

what to do to solve the following issue?

Answer (score 0):

The *.o file is the object file created by the compiler and used by the linker to create the *.exe file. Since it is unnecessary, you can delete it if you already have the *.exe file.

Comment: Yeah i can but why in the home directory ? Can i config atom to store that *.o file anywhere else ? It's annoying to delete the *.o files once in a while .. please help @Nejc Galof

Answer (score 0):

You can delete **.o* file instantly with `-o /dev/null` and after **.exe* is created, **.o* files are deleted automatically.